# Is it possible in css to add additional classes to an element with a specific class name?

Tags: css

Assume that I am using the following icon in multiple places in my code to represent delete icon:

```
<i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
```

If after a while I decide to change the icon to something else like:

```
<i class="fas fa-eraser"></i>
```

I have to go and find all the instances of the first icon and change the class name to `fas fa-eraser` which may be painful if the source code is huge.

What I like to do is to have a class name like `delete-icon` and add it to every delete icon element that I have like:

```
<i class="delete-icon"></i>
```

and then somehow in my css styles, have a rule like:

```
.delete-icon {
    ?....[add fas]
    ?....[add fa-eraser]
}
```

Is it possible to have such rule in css?

Comment: No, it is not. With JS yes, with pure CSS - no.

Comment: no css is a styling language, you cannot manipulate dom attributes with it

Comment: got it. Thanks :)

Comment: why not just add it to those delcarations: `.fas, .delete-icon {}` and `.fa-eraser, .delete-icon {}` etc

Comment: @Pete  I didn't get what you mean. can you explain more please?

Comment: If you are adventurous, you can have a look at [Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components). Using them, you could replace your code with something like `<the-icon></the-icon>`.

Comment: if you want the delete class to have the properties of the other 2 classes, just add the delete class to the declaration where the other 2 are defined

Comment: instead of having a class like `delete-icon` assign an `id` to all those elements where you want delete-icons and using JS get all those elements and add the required class for that icon

Comment: @Pete Those classes are from [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/), you can't "just" add their content to your own classes.

Comment: @str you can if you're not bothered about the upgrade path and download the stylesheet although I don't understand what's wrong with doing a find and replace all *IF* the OP ever decides to change the icon

Comment: thanks Pete, I think I'll go with @str suggestion. As I'm developing in Django, I can have each of the icon definitions in one template and whenever I have to use one, I just include the appropriate template.

Comment: @Ehsan no problems, just make sure you have the correct browser support: [version 1](https://caniuse.com/#feat=custom-elementsv1) or [version 0](https://caniuse.com/#feat=custom-elements)

Comment: @Pete Actually I'll not create new html tags. Django support templates, and when I include a template somewhere, django will replace it with the html inside that template.

Comment: Ah ok - you meant django templates including normal html  - thought you meant create a template that contained a custom component :)

Answer (score -3):

Have a look at sass which is a great css pre-processor.It allows you to write css code and has great features like variable,inheritance among others